# Remove additional space before section in tcolorbox

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox

When I set the `parbox` option of a `tcolorbox` to `false`, every section, even the first one, is preceded with additional whitespace. Is there any way to tell `tcolorbox` to handle the first `section` (`subsection`, ...) in the same way as the first `section` on a page is treated, that is without additional space? That is, the following two boxes should look the same independent of the `parbox` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\section{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\section{Test}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want to place a box around a section (subsection etc.)?

Comment: If you omit `parbox=false` and use `top=0pt,bottom=0pt` as option instead, it should work

Comment: I want to use `parbox=false` because I'd like to use the "normal" `parskip` behavior within the box. The content of the box is generated from markdown, therefore, I'd like to leave the content as is, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It work as you want it if one removes the `\noindent` and `\leavevmode` (inserted by tcolorbox) from `\@parboxrestore`. But as I don't understand why tcolorbox tries so hard to switch to horizontal mode at the start of the box I don't know if this has unwanted side-effects:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@parbox@use@false{%
  \def\@parboxrestore{\linewidth\hsize\let\@parboxrestore=\tcb@parboxrestore}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\section{Test}
abc\par cde
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\section{Test}
abc\par cde
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will check whether this change has undesired side-effects in my case. When I increase the `parskip`, the skip is also added to the top of the box. Is there a more elegant way to remove this skip than using a negative `vspace` at the top of the box?